# MapsEngine + GeoLocation Javascript API

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-engine, google-maps-engine-lite

How can I use the Geolocation Javascript API with my Google MapsEngine custom map?

I have made a mall map and I would like to use this: 
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-geolocation

To my map here:
https://mapsengine.google.com/map/edit?mid=zw7uoGNV7Gvo.kuA1Rc-lcUsI

But I don't know how and I can't find any instructions online of how to use geolocation in my custom map made by Google MapsEngine. :(

I hope any Google Maps expert here can point me to the right direction. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to create your own JavaScript app using the [JS Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/), adding a [Maps Engine Layer](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/layer-dynamicmapsengine), then you will be able to use the Geolocation service you linked.

The catch is that you appear to be using Maps Engine Lite or Pro, neither of which are supported in the Maps Engine Layer (or in the [Maps Engine API](https://developers.google.com/maps-engine/)). If you move your data to the [Maps Engine](https://www.google.com.au/intx/en_au/enterprise/mapsearth/products/mapsengine.html) product, then you will be able to use these features.

Comment: Thanks. I'm using Pro. I don't know about the Maps Engine product, but will take a look at it. Thanks for sharing Mark McDonald. :)

Comment: Saw the MapsEngine now. It's awesome. I'm still playing around with it. I wonder why I can't draw polygons with Maps Engine, only in Maps Engine Pro. O_O. I'll just post another question regarding this.